# Get only the response body in gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I need to parse an id from the response body and send it in the next request body in gatling for session based users. If anyone has an idea about that, please share it.

I have used the `.check(regex())` and `.saveAs` method, but that saves the data in session, for which I need to do a complex parsing which I dont want.

Answer (score 0):

Save it in the session using:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.id").saveAs("id"))
```

To send it in the next request, extract it first using

```
val id = session.get("id").as[String]
```

Alternatively, if you want to use it in the next request in the chain:

```
def get(token: String, org: String): ChainBuilder = {
    val url = MY_SERVICE_URI + "/${id}"
    exec(http("Get something")
      .get(url)
      .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, token)
      //etc'
```